# legends repeating sns heatmap after passing Func Animation

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

My code below works well. The only problem is after every 'n' seconds (as I am using func Animation).It repeats heatmap legends which is what I dont expect. Any solution.

See the chart below where heatmap legend bar repeating and figure is shrinking.

[image: Figure1]

My code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
import csv
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib as mpl
from NumTOWord import numberToText, spellNumber
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib as mpl
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

### main Df name is OI_df

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

plt.style.use('seaborn-paper')  # switch to seaborn style  seaborn-paper, seaborn tick


def animate(i):

    startTime = datetime.now()
    url = 'url'
    driver.get(url)

    html = driver.page_source

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    table = soup.findAll('table', {'id': 'someid'})

    for trs in table:
        rows = trs.findAll('tr')
        xs = []
        ys = []
        datarowList = []  # M1 Start classic expample of making df from multiple list
        for row in rows[2:-1]:
            datarowList.append(Num_DatRows)
            OI_df = pd.DataFrame(datarowList, columns=headers)

            OI_df.to_csv('out.csv')

        x = OI_df['OI_ce'].values

        y = OI_df['LTP_ce'].values

        # ax1.plot(x,y) # Call
        # ax1.matshow(OI_df.corr())

        ax1.clear()
        corr = OI_df.corr()
        sns.heatmap(corr, xticklabels=corr.columns.values,
                    yticklabels=corr.columns.values, ax=ax1)


        # sns.pairplot(OI_df)
        # sns.pairplot(df, vars=[columns_names])

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. Instead of using animation, I just retried something simple like this, it finally worked for me:

```
for t in range(0,1700):
    current_score=overall_Score[t:t+10,:]
    plt.clf()
    sns.heatmap(current_score)
    plt.pause(0.1)
```

Please give this solution a thumbs up, if it helps... A thumbs up would help me a big time... ;)